# Alternative to dex2jar and jd-GUI?

Tags: java, android, decompiling, dex2jar

it seems that either [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and/or [jd-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) gives bad de-obfuscation even for the simplest code of if-else condition (they show a `while(true)` loop which has a `return;` on its first line .

are there any other freeware apps that do the same work of de-obfuscation? maybe something that can also use the mapping file of proguard ?

Comment: Any java (.class) decompiler works if you run the apk through dex2jar. There is unfortunately no real alternative to jd-gui I know of. http://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/JavaDecompilers lists some but they all seem to be older / unsupported / no longer available

Comment: i've found the next one: http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/01/31/for-developers-jeb-is-a-powerful-new-decompiler-for-android-apps-but-its-not-cheap/ , but even though it's really good, it's also very expensive (1000$ for a single license!!!) . the link contains some other alternatives though

Comment: 2021/2022 update: I found this and it works well: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17851-jadx-android-decompiler

Comment: @Lorenzo Interesting! Does it work well?

Answer (score 4):

Actually the best alternative that I have tested is [JEB Decompiler](http://www.android-decompiler.com/index.php) that works directly on Dalvik bytecode to generate the sources without conversion in Java bytecode(that is the main source of errors in decompilation procedure), but unfortunately is a commercial software a bit expensive for an individual.

Alternatively try [Kivlad](http://www.matasano.com/research/kivlad/) , but note that requires [Ruby runtime 1.x](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) to run, and is still an alpha release in development

[Virtuous Ten Studio (VTS)](http://virtuous-ten-studio.com/) is another nice tool that uses APKtool as engine, the quality of java src result is inferior to JEB and comparable to *dex2jar* + *java decompiler*, but the environment is very comfortable. (Has a donate license but works for free)

Comment: yes, it does look very promising, but as i've written, i ask for a free tool. not only this tool isn't free, it costs really a lot...

Comment: Unfortunately actually there aren't much affordable choices. You can try Kivlad but is still an Alpha not comparable to Jeb

Comment: it actually looks promising. i hope they succeed making it a good tool.

Comment: how do you use "Kivlad" ? I've tried to write what they wrote on the readme, but it doesn't work: "ruby reflect.rb PACKAGE_NAME" . I also don't get where are the options being mentioned...